# Partial option parsing (python / getopt)

Tags: python, getopt

Using Python library / (gnu_)getopt  / optparse / argparse,  how can I best exclude from parsing the **rest of options & arguments** after option **`-r`** consistently and take that rest (for forwarding it to another sub-process, module, ... )

Call example (the bold part is wanted here - its the **rest** after `-r` really matches):

> program.py -ac cval -bdr "val -ra" file -droot -are **--rest-opt -x -yr restargs -z**

Definition / Starting from:

```
shortopts, longopts = 'abc:d:ehr', ['help']
opts, files = getopt.gnu_getopt(argv1, shortopts, longopts)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

POSIX says "dash dash", so use

`program.py -ac cval -bdr "val -ra" file -droot -are -- -x -yr restargs -z`